# How do I find the key that looks like ^ with _ on top of it?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

The keyboard shortcut for sending an email in Thunderbird looks like this:

[image]

I know that the first symbol is the Command key, but I can't figure out the second symbol.

I have looked at the [Apple support article](https://support.apple.com/en-au/guide/mac-help/what-are-those-symbols-shown-in-menus-cpmh0011/mac) about menu symbols, but it doesn't have this symbol!